# How to use socket.io with express-session that coming from controller

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my app.js ı using route in middleware like this:

```
app.use('/myPage', pageRoute);
```

my route page:

```
router.get('/new', pageController.pageFunc);
```

and my controller:

```
exports.pageFunc = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('myPage/pugFile', {
        name: req.session.userName
    });
}
```

Its working perfectly but i want use this session with my socket in my app.js
my socket is like this:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('myIo', (par) => {
    console.log(par);
  });
});
```

if i try to use req.session.userName in my socket i taking req is not defined error. How can i use my sessions in this socket?

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with middleware like this:

```
app.use('/myPage', pageRoute);

let mySession;

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
mySession = req.session.userName;
next();
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('myIo', () => {
    console.log(mySession );
  });
});
```

EDIT: There are some problems in this solution , because mySession value changing with other user connection but finally i found solution.

You can use socket.request.session they explain how you can use in there: [Usage with express-session](https://socket.io/docs/v3/faq/)